# Cygwin/X beginner trouble

Tags: cygwin

I have got SSH on my remote ubuntu box and Remote desktop enabled. I am trying to use X-windows on my Windows machine.

I have installed Cygwin/X - however the [user guide](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/cygwin-x-ug.html) tells me how to run XServer in Windows. I would like to connect to my Ubuntu machine (I have verified that this box X11 + Port forwarding done correctly as I can ssh -x into that box from a remote linux box).

I have done [this](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-remote-session.html) but I get the following error:

> 2 [main] Xwin 9192 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization, retry 0, exit code 0x600, errno 11

Can someone explain how to use Windows Cygwin/X and open up windows of a remote Ubuntu box?

Comment: Is your windows 64bit or 32bit?

Comment: 32 bit windows :)

Answer (score 2):

I probably has nothing to do with Xwin, but is probably a problem with fork()

Try this:

```
Due to issues with Cygwin's fork() and DLL base address
conflicts, one should rebase their Cygwin system to prevent fork()
failures.  Use the following procedure to rebase your system:

a. install the Cygwin rebase package (if necessary)  
b. shutdown all Cygwin processes  
c. start bash (do not use rxvt)  
d. execute rebaseall (in the bash window)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to simply connect to a linux box, from windows, is with something simply like PuTTY (which is free to download).

If you can't connect with PuTTY then you may have a networking of firewall problem (although from your description Nifle's suggestion of a DLL problem sounds right).

PuTTY will also provide you with X11 forwarding, so you won't have to use ssh -x directly.

If PuTTY works and ssh -x from within a Cygwin shell, doesn't, then try Nifle's forking/rebase solution.

If you want to get X Forwarding to work with Cygwin/X and PuTTY as a terminal window, follow my instructions here: [How do I get X11 Forwarding to work on Windows with PuTTY and Xming?](https://superuser.com/questions/592185/how-do-i-get-x11-forwarding-to-work-on-windows-with-putty-and-xming/922254#922254) At the very least, you may need to configure the -listen tcp bit of Cygwin/X, so it will accept incoming X connections (if you're X forwarding from bash running on Cygwin, then the XAUTHORITY parameter will probably already be set, so the 2nd part of the instructions will be moot)